# How to make multiple Http calls

Tags: angular, http

Here I make one Http request where i get the Account ID:

```
getAccountId(accessToken){
console.log(accessToken);
this.http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/access-tokens/'+ accessToken)
.subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data.json().items[0].account_id);
    },
       error=>console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Using this **account_id** obtained there I want to make another Http call to this API to get the UserId:

```
 this.http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+ this.AccountId +'/associated')
```

How do i do this? any solutions?

Comment: Please edit your previous question if you think its not a duplicate. Don't ask the same question again in a different format. The link already states that you should be using `flatMap`. What is the issue?

Comment: can i pass value from one http request to other http request using flatMap @echonax

Comment: That's the whole purpose of `flatMap`

Comment: In the above code after querying i have got the account_id . How do i pass this to the flatMap @echonax

Comment: `this.http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/access-tokens/'+ accessToken).flatMap((data)=> this.http.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/'+ data.json().items[0].account_id +'/associated')).subscribe((data)=> console.log(data);)`

Comment: thank you it worked! Thanks a lot!@echonax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152172/discussion-between-samson-and-echonax).